# Where exactly does R' Saadia Gaon explain why a woman marrying two men is מתנגד לשכל?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parashat-bereishit, creation, saadya-gaon, polygamy

ר' סעדיה גאון על בראשית ד׳:י״ח

"וכבר ביארנו קודם בפרשת מעשה אדם שהשכל מתנגד לנשואי אשה אחת לשני אנשים, אבל אינו מתנגד לנשואי שתי נשים לאיש אחד"

Can someone give me an exact location for the "kvar biarnu" that he mentions?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you check near 2:24 or 1:27? Seems like the natural place

Comment: this would be polyandry not polygamy

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that if you care about paternity, two men and one woman just does not work.